# Tensorflow serving error "{ "error": "Malformed request: POST /v1/models/cloths:predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, post, computer-vision, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to predict image category using tensorflow serving. I have used a docker container and deployed model in server. Now docker container is running and when try to send post request to predict class of an image, I get this error

> "Tensorflow serving error "{ "error": "Malformed request: POST /v1/models/cloths:predict"

What should I do to send correct post request to my model to get correct np array output?

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np 
import requests 
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input

SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:8501/v1/models/cloths:predict'
i = '1522972-1.jpg'
#dl_request = requests.get(IMAGE_URL, stream=True)
img = image.load_img(i, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
value = {"instances":x}
response = requests.post(SERVER_URL,params=value)
#response.raise_for_status()
#print(x)
#print(response)
```

I tried commenting `response = requests.post(SERVER_URL,params=value)` and print my 4D "x" image to check whether input is correct and it returns correct 4D numpy array of my image. Something wrong with post request.
I am using pre-trained MobileNetV2, which takes as a input 4D array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should send your request like this

```
requests.post(SERVER_URL, data=json.dumps(value))
```